# Getting data from AsyncTask class to the Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to retrieve data from the AsyncTask class's onPostExecute() and set it as the text for textviews of the same activity (so just to test i am using toast to see if it works).

I am using an interface (with method processFinish()) as follows to get data from onPostExecute().

But the data is not available to the Outer Activity class : -

```
interface AsyncResponse{
  void processFinish(String[][] output);
    }
```

MainActivity -

```
 public class VPmovies extends Activity implements AsyncResponse  {
  MyAsyncClass myAsyncClass  = new MyAsyncClass();
  String[][] mov_details;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      myAsyncClass.asyncResponse=this;
      myAsyncClass.execute();
      mov_details=new String[6][9];

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vpmovies);

   Toast.makeText(this,"onCreate"+mov_details[0][1],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


  // output from here is - "onCreate**null**"
   }

  public void processFinish(String[][] output) {

               mov_details = output;

    }
```

MyAsyncClass's onPostExecute() -

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String[][] strings) {
      //  super.onPostExecute(strings);
         asyncResponse.processFinish(strings);
        Toast.makeText(VPmovies.this,"onPostToast"+strings[1][0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //THIS prints the data from the array successfully
    }
```

Is the AsyncTask Class still performing its operation in background while onCreate() is executed ? Is that why i am getting null for the array element ?
Is there a way to delay onCreate() to be executed after AsyncTask completes its operation ?

Comment: Data shall be available in your `processFinish()`… Not in onCreate(), as activity is already created and then asycTask is performed.

Comment: You wont get result in `onCreate` `Toast` because `AsyncTask` runs under worker thread, better toast it in `processFinish()` method where you will get your result.

Comment: One more thing , `onCreate Toast` prints as the first Toast ,  I want to run the task in the processFinish() first  , will it work ?

Comment: Thanks Bharat , it worked (y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()) method of AsyncTask class for adding delay in execution of onCreate().Such as -

myAsyncClass.execute().get();

Comment: Woah , that was the best and easiest solution. Thanks Abhijeet . I can't believe i wasted so much time for this , there is not even need for an interface to get data from AsyncTask , Plus the solution is best for me because i wanted to update my activity screen from the result of the AsyncTask.